# Button to force recalculation (Application.Volatile?)

Tags: vba, excel

I am working on a complex Excel file with 15+ sheets and at least 40 cells with Macros in it. I removed `Application.Volatile` from the macros itself, since it caused up to 10 secounds of lag after every change in a cell. I just found the possibillity to creat buttons with a marco. Is it possible to make a simple button that `Application.Volatile` on every single formular on every sheet?

```
Sub ReCalculate()
      Function Volatile()
      Application.Volatile
      End Function
    End Sub
```

This is my first try on a custom button, and its not working. Anyone know how to make this simple button? Google and the search function sadly didnt list any solving tips for my problem.

Comment: Why not [Worksheet.Calculate Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Excel.Worksheet.Calculate(method))

Comment: @SiddharthRout `Sub ReCalculate()
   Application.Calculate
End Sub` isnt working for me. I dont understand the synstax of buttons yet. I try to learn it by myself, but doesnt work yet. Started with vba macros today.

Comment: Try `Application.CalculateFull`

Comment: @SiddharthRout this worked for me! Thank you!